# Function Using Generic Type

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'd like to make a function that replicates the effects of something like nvl2. To do this I created a function that looks like

```
  function nvl2(in_checkNull anydata, not_null_return_value anydata, null_return_value anydata) return anydata is
  begin
    if in_checkNull is null then
      return null_return_value;
    else
      return not_null_return_value;
    end if;
  end;
```

The problem with this is that I want to call the function like

```
nvl2(my_type, my_type.my_number, 0);
```

But it's not working. I looked into the problem and it seems I need to cast everything to the anydata type but this defeats the point since now I may as well just write out the entire if statement. Is there anyway to make this function work without having to go through painful and verbose casts and setup?

Comment: Do you really want to handle *any* type?  Or just a defined set of data types (say, the various predefined data types)?  In a package, you can define overloaded procedures (procedures with the same name but different signatures).  So you can have a function `a` that takes a `date` and one that takes a `number` and a third that takes a `varchar2`.  http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97630_01/appdev.920/a96624/08_subs.htm#12353

Comment: I'd prefer it's able to handle any type that can be null, just as nvl2 is able to.

Comment: Take a look at the package specification for `SYS.STANDARD`.  You'll see Oracle has `NVL` overloaded for each data type.  I think that's the most likely approach for you.

Comment: @user2488335 - I doubt (without checking) that `nvl2` could handle, say, a user-defined object type.  So I wouldn't expect that it could actually handle any type.  It only has overloads for the various built-in type families (i.e. one where it takes a `number`, one where it takes a `varchar2`, one with a `date`).  That's what you can do.  You can add overloads for your custom types as well assuming you have a fixed number of them.

Comment: Darn that's too bad. Coming from a C# background the lack of inheritance requires a little different thinking.